# Replace text in Wordpress custom fields with image using Jquery

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I am trying to replace the text of some custom fields in Wordpress. I would normally use CSS for this but this isn't possible (I don't think) without using jQuery.

The code:

```
 <div class="CustomRow left"><span>Vehicle Length (ft):</span> 25</div>

 <div class="CustomRow right"><span>Level Parking:</span> yes</div>

 <div class="CustomRow left"><span>Water:</span> no</div>

 <div class="CustomRow right"><span>Grey Water:</span> no</div>

 <div class="CustomRow left"><span>Black Water:</span> no</div>

 <div class="CustomRow right"><span>Electric:</span> no</div>

 <div class="CustomRow left"><span>Extra Night:</span> no</div>
```

I want to replace the text so that a separate image for each div is shown if "Yes" is the value of the div. The image is determined by the value in the  tags.

If the value is "No" then no image is to be shown. The div classes are fixed and I have tried to add a class to the spans but to no avail.

Any ideas?

Edit to add:

I've had a bit more of a play around and I think I'm almost there but still no joy:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.CustomRow').each(function(i, e) {
    if (m = (text = $(e).text().trim()).match(re = /: +(yes|no)$/)) {
        class = $('span', e).text().replace(/[^\w]/g, '').toLowerCase();

    }
});

if ($('.levelparking') = (text = $(e).text().trim()).match(re = /: +(yes)$/)) {
// you can check div class here to determine the image
$('.levelparking').html('<img src="images/level_ground.jpg">');
}

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my solution. It goes through all of the CustomRow elements, searching for a text that ends with `: yes`. For every found element it adds a `.yes` class, and replaces `: yes` with an empty string.

Here's a fiddle that shows it in action: http://jsfiddle.net/N24R7/1/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.CustomRow').each(function(i, e) {
        if ((text = $(e).text().trim()).match(re = /: +yes$/)) {
            $(e).addClass('yes').text(text.replace(re, ''));
        }
    });
});
```

**update:** Added more improvements - http://jsfiddle.net/N24R7/2/

---

In response to your comment with this code - it doesn't work as expected, because `.text(text.replace(re, ''))` strips "yes" from the text, so your code can't `match(/yes/)` anymore. You just need to remove that bit (it's commented out in a code below) and it will work

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.CustomRow').each(function(i, e) {
        if (m = (text = $(e).text().trim()).match(re = /: +(yes|no)$/)) {
            var class = $('span', e).text().replace(/[^\w]/g, '').toLowerCase();
            $(e)
                .addClass(class)
//              .text(text.replace(re, ''))
            ;
        }
    });
    if ($('.levelparking').html().match(/yes/)) {
        $('.levelparking').html('<img src="levelparking.jpg">');
    }
    if ($('.water').html().match(/yes/)) {
        $('.water').html('<img src="water.jpg">');
    }
});
```

Comment: Thats great and just about there - but I need to replace the labels with images depending on the Yes/No answer. I.e. I will have an image called "water" that will replace the text for Water if the value is yes. Is it possible so that the code, instead of adding classes for Yes and No, would add a class that was determined by the label in the span tags?

Comment: Yeah, you can do all sorts of stuff with matching elements: http://jsfiddle.net/N24R7/3/. Maybe it will be easier to do with a Wordpress help though?

Comment: Still struggling to get this to work. I've tried to use the above code to change the classes of the custom fields and then used an amended version of the code below (from Jack Duluoz) to replace the text but this isn't working. Any ideas? Thanks in advance...again

Comment: Sorry for delay in getting back. My code is as follows: $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.CustomRow').each(function(i, e) {
        if (m = (text = $(e).text().trim()).match(re = /: +(yes|no)$/)) {
            class = $('span', e).text().replace(/[^\w]/g, '').toLowerCase();
            $(e).addClass(class).text(text.replace(re, ''));
        }
    });
 
 if ($('.levelparking').html().match(/yes/)) {
    
    $('.levelparking').html('<img src="levelparking.jpg">');
 }
 
 if ($('.water').html().match(/yes/)) {
    
    $('.water').html('<img src="water.jpg">');
 }

});

Comment: Brilliant - that works perfectly. I've adapted it to hide any div with 'no' in it so only divs with yes are shown. Thanks very much for your help and pateince

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand how the image to load is determined, but generally something like this should work:

```
if ($('#div-id').html().match(/yes/)) {
    // you can check div class here to determine the image
    $('#div-id').html('<img src="image.jpg">');
}
```

This is just an example and it has some problems, but it may show you how to procede

Answer (score 0):

Can you edit the PHP code of the theme displaying the page? If so, then why not simply having the PHP code insert the image for you?

```
<?php
  if (!strcmp($custom_field, 'yes')) 
    echo "<img src='yes.png' />"; 
  else if (!strcmp($custom_field, 'no')) 
    echo "<img src='no.png' />"; 
  else 
    echo $custom_field;
?>
```